# How to know if there are rows retrieved in query | clickhouse and GOlang

Tags: database, go, datarow, clickhouse

There's a way to know if a query retrieved data from clickhouse database using GOlang?

I have this:

```
dataRows, err := connect.Query(dbQuery)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer dataRows.Close()
```

I'm wondering if you could do something like:

```
var rowsRetrieved int = dataRows.RowsCount
```

Thanks, i'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it an iterator (can you use `.Next()` method on it)? If so, and if it doesn't have a `RowsCount` or equivalent, you probably have to iterate on the rows and count them that way. Provide a link to the package you're using and I can dig further.

Comment: I'm using this driver to connect to clickhouse: `https://github.com/mailru/go-clickhouse`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to know whether there were *any* rows, you could do:

```
dataRows, err := connect.Query(dbQuery)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer dataRows.Close()
if hasRows := dataRows.Next(); hasRows {
    handleRow(dataRows)
    for dataRows.Next() {
        handleRow(dataRows)
    }
} else {
    // has no rows
}

func handleRow(rows *sql.Rows) {
    // handle the row
}
```

Comment: What I've found is that if you use .Next() function, it will iterate 1 datarow and it will start with the second for ex: you have 2 records, if you use .Next() function and iterate after use .Next() it will start at 2nd record.